# How to call ivy-occur programmatically?

Tags: minibuffer, ivy, occur

I would like to programmatically call an ivy or counsel function and then immediately execute `ivy-occur` to get the ivy-occur buffer.

Example:
Instead of doing `M-x counsel-describe-function` and `C-c C-o` manually to get the ivy-occur buffer I would to do this with a function.

---

Tried the following (the last three solution work but there has to be a better way):

#### Minibuffer-setup-hook

Works for some (counsel-M-x) but most commands give me an ivy-occur buffer with 0 candidates. So this is probably called too early:

```lisp
(unwind-protect 
    (progn
      (add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'ivy-occur)
      (ignore-errors (counsel-faces)))
  (remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'ivy-occur))
```

#### Minibuffer-with-setup-hook

Same problem as with the hook.

```lisp
(ignore-errors
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    (:append #'ivy-occur)
  (counsel-faces)))
```

#### Execute-kbd-macro

This actually works, but there has to be a better way to do this. This just simulates the keys pressed:

```lisp
(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "M-x counsel-faces RET C-c C-o"))

;; Can even change the initial input like this (`ivy-`).
(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "M-x counsel-faces RET ivy- C-c C-o"))
```

#### Run-with-idle-timer

This works as well but is sort of strange too. Not even sure if this might be run before calling `counsel-faces` in some cases.

```lisp
(progn
  (run-with-idle-timer 0.01 nil #'ivy-occur)
  (counsel-faces))
```

#### Unread-command-events

Found this in the question [Clean way to perform commands in the Emacs minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11380918/1365754). But this also feels akward.

```lisp
(progn
  (setq unread-command-events
      (append (listify-key-sequence (kbd "C-c C-o")) unread-command-events))
  (counsel-faces))
```

---

Thanks for any solution or a hint on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [found](https://oremacs.com/2015/07/16/callback-quit/) a working solution that feels ok:

> `run-at-time` with the argument `nil` will run the code as soon as possible, which is almost exactly after we're back into the command loop.

```lisp
(progn
  (run-at-time nil nil #'ivy-occur)
  (counsel-faces))
```